# Postgres 9.4 is restored from daily backup and its not starting up

Tags: postgresql

Our database got into I/O issue and we are restoring the database from daily backup.

When we start the server, we have find the below logs.

Can you please help how to resolve and start the database.

```
2022-04-09 09:52:52 GST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2022-04-09 09:52:52 GST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2022-04-09 09:52:52 GST LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1CAD/1E000000 in log segment 0000000100001C5C0000001B, offset 0
2022-04-09 09:52:52 GST LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2022-04-09 09:52:52 GST LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1CAC/FA000000 in log segment 0000000100001C5C0000000F, offset 0
2022-04-09 09:52:52 GST LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
2022-04-09 09:52:52 GST PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2022-04-09 09:52:52 GST LOG:  startup process (PID 128949) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2022-04-09 09:52:52 GST LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like your backup is not valid.  How did you take it? Had you ever tested the method before?

Comment: In our vendor client cloud infrastructure, the disk got into issue.  Hence we recovered the data from the last snapshot and we are getting this issue when we start the server using recovered data

Comment: it seems like the snapshot wasn't really a snapshot.